# @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) not working

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, annotations

I am trying to remove the null value at the class level by adding the annotation @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
but it doesnt work.

My class structure is like below

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
Class A extends BaseClass {
private String B;
private C;
}
```

```
Class C{
private String d;
private String e;
}
```

```
Request json 
{
  B: "xyz";
  C: null;
}
```

As C is assigned null, I don't want it to be considered while serializing. Any inputs will be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a reproducher, e.g. in form of a git repository?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that Jackson is not properly configured or the annotation is not being applied to the objects you're serializing.

Here are some troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue:

**Verify Jackson Configuration:** Make sure that you have configured Jackson properly in your application. If you're using Spring Boot, Jackson configuration is usually auto-configured, but you may need to customize it for specific behavior.

Example Spring Boot Configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

**Check Object Instantiation:** Ensure that the object you're serializing is instantiated and not null. If the object itself is null, Jackson won't have anything to serialize, and the `@JsonInclude` annotation won't have any effect.

**Update Jackson Version:** If you're using an older version of Jackson, consider upgrading to a newer version. Newer versions may have bug fixes or improvements related to serialization behavior.

**Verify Object Fields:** Check if the fields within your object are properly annotated or configured for serialization. If a field is explicitly annotated with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` or `@JsonProperty`, it may override the class-level annotation.

The below configuration works for me.

Object:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class A extends TestA {
    public A(String b, C c) {
        B = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    private String B;
    private C c;

    public String getB() { return B; }
    public void setB(String b) { B = b; }
    public C getC() { return c; }
    public void setC(C c) { this.c = c; }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/q77984356")
    @GetMapping
    public A q77984356() {
       return new A("xyz", null);
    }
```

Postman Request:
[image]

I hope this helps you.
I'm using Java 15 & spring-boot 2.7.6.